# Ошибка после конвертации python скрипта в exe файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, urllib, яндекс-переводчик

На вопрос как ответ нашел, но появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from yandex_translate import YandexTranslate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "yandex_translate/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "requests/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "requests/models.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 158, in load_module
    return self._importer.load_module(fullname, self._fullname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection'
Failed to execute script main
```

Установил, все пакеты разными способами,все модули есть в списке. Приложение работает. При попытке запустить исполняемый файл после pyinstaller получаю список ошибок. Как это исправить?

Comment: Какая версия requests?

Comment: @m9_psy Version: 2.13.0